# What is the meaning of the phrase "no sooner than"?

Tags: tense, expressions, time-words

*1.* *He was no sooner graduated than he was on his way to California.*

*2.*  *No sooner had the plane taken off than I regretted not taking the train.*

Above are the examples of using the phrase "no sooner than" which I found in some textbook. Why is not used Past Perfect in the first sentence as it is so in the second one? Would it be a mistake to write: He had not been no sooner graduated then he was on his way to California.

Answer (score 1):

The construction, which basically states that the two events which are compared are simultaneous, gives no reason to prefer either a past perfect or a simple past in either part.

The inversion in the front clause is likely to confuse you—it tends to confuse native speakers, too, when they try to analyze it instead of just using it as a fixed expression. Here's the logic:

> ***`No sooner {had X happened / did X happen}    than Y happened`*** ... *may be 'disinverted' as*
>   ***`X {did not happen / had not happened} sooner than Y happened`*** ... *which is equivalent to saying that*
>   ***`No time elapsed between X happening and Y happening`*** ... *in other words, the two events were simultaneous.*

(That's not quite true—Y might have happened *before* X—but that possibility isn't what this idiom is about: the important point is denying that X happened before Y.)

In any case, *X **had not happened** before Y happened* doesn't mean anything different from *X **did not happen** before Y happened*. You are free to use whatever construction suits your narrative purposes.

Comment: Well, it *was* Saturday night last night! But even if I weren't feeling slightly withered today, the precise "logic" of how the idiom "works" would always be a bit confusing to me. I know what it means, and how to use it, but if I was asked to "deconstruct" it again in a few years time I'd probably still flounder about!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm never confident that any of these fixed expressions actually makes sense and hasn't been garbled in transmission, but every once in a while one does.

Comment: I'm going AFK for a while, but assuming it hasn't already been covered here (and isn't easy to Google), I might be tempted to ask for a deconstruction of *FumbleFingers deleted his crap answer - and **not before time!***

Comment: @StoneyB   
I want to use " No sooner ... than" in a formal text for my essay. Is it possible to use this for formal sentences like the below one? I do not know it would be ok to use them in these sentences.

 - The pessimist holds the conviction that no sooner do universities solve the reduction of enrollments than take a drastic action against the spiraling tuition
 
- The first example means : Universities should first take a drastic measure against tuition then the reduction in enrollment would be resolved . 
 Is it true?! Are they equivalent?

Comment: @BaharJafariZadeh No, they are not. "No sooner A . . . than B" means that B will follow A immediately.

Comment: @StoneyB could u put my words in this structure?

Comment: @BaharJafariZadeh I don't think the structure says what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

When "*no sooner* do something *than* do something else" is used, by the time the second "do" starts to occur, the first "do" is in the past.

In the first sentence, graduation is an event, not a process, and a very fixed as far as the sentence is concerned (since it talks about the graduation as immediately followed by being on the way to California).  Using a Perfect Tense would be to indicate that the result of it is important, but not the moment in time.

In the second sentence, however, *taking off* is a process (although there is a moment at which the landing gear separates from the ground), and it is *the result of it* that is important (the plane is in the air), so using a Perfect Tense is justified.

We can rewrite the second sentence as

> No sooner **was** the plane in the air than I regretted not taking the train.

Comment: what about "After the plane took off, I regretted not taking the train." I think from context we can infer the chronological events properly. thus, it is not necessary to use had+pp to declare the orders of the events.

Comment: For inferring the sequence it serves fine.  It does not, however, provide the *necessary immediacy* for which the "no sooner ... than ..." is used.  And as far as Past Perfect is concerned, I thought I'd explained that.

Comment: @VictorBazarov However, with a different preposition Cardinal's version would work.  "As soon as the plane took off, I regretted..." for instance.

Comment: Yes, "as soon as ..., ..." works almost as well.  I think that the negative in "no sooner ... than ..." gives the edge to it, though.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom "no sooner....than" is used to show that one thing happens immediately after another thing; you can use "as soon as" to replace the idiom when a sentence is in the past. You usually use the past perfect with "no sooner", but the use of the past simple is also possible.

He was no sooner graduated than he was on his way to California or

He had no sooner been graduated than he was on his way to California.

You can also start the sentence with "No sooner was he/had he been".

No sooner had the plane taken off than I regretted not taking the train or

The plane had no sooner taken off than I...............................".